# How to append HTTP heaeder for all requests into router

Tags: nginx, proxy, wifi, openwrt

The problem is as below:

1. Business owner wants to provide free internet to clients (Guest
   WiFi).
2. Clients should land on the web site of the business once
   connected.
3. All requests to the web site (through the WIFI router)
   should have an HTTP header identifies users comes from that router.
4. All other web surfing should be working normally without any
   additions or manipulation.

That process is to serve those clients differently than the normal visitors of the web site.

Comment: I think the nginx proxy + lua can implement your feature.

Comment: I did not work before in networking and do not know if it could be done into openwrt or other tools!! is there any resource describing that topic you can share?